# XCode 4.5 Compiling Framework C++ Files

Tags: frameworks, compilation, header

I have just started receiving compile error - 
In a file - CAMediaTiming.h (which is I believe part of QuartzCore Framework).

@class NSString; -------- Prefix Attribute must be followed by an interface or protocol.

Upon searching through StackOverflow, I have deduced that this is a C File (so it should allow @class) however, Xcode should not be compiling this again...

I don't know how this happened as I haven't touched any of the Build settings and in fact, I had just added a simple line into an auxiliary class  - I put this line in....
([numberArray removeAllObjects];) 
Then I took it back out and still get the problem so that was a dead end :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem -

Basically, in one of the .m files, I had the standard comments...

```
//  filename.m
//
// Created by......
// Copyright  .....
//
```

Somehow, I (It must have been me because it's a solo project, but I swear I didn't do this)
so - IT changed itself to...

```
UIButton//
//  filename.m
//
// Created by......
// Copyright.....
//
```

Upon doing some experimentation, depending upon which file this is in could cause a myriad of compiler errors in unrelated files.